# Embed Container View with Navigation Controller Programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uicontainerview

I want to embed a Navigation controller with the container view and use the same navigation controller to push some other view controller. Here is the workaround with the help of storyboard.[image]

Can I embed the navigation controller with Container View programmatically? I can able to add SecondViewController's content as a subview in the container view. But in that case, my Navigation controller will not work.

In the BaseViewController I have added this code,

```
let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController")
let navigationController = CustomNavigation(rootViewController: secondViewController!)
// taking a navigation controller reference, so that I can use this to Push other view controller.
Helper.shared.customNavController = navigationController 
self.addChildViewController(navigationController)
secondViewController?.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: containerView.frame.size.width, height: containerView.frame.size.height)
containerView.addSubview((secondViewController?.view)!)
```

It added the SecondViewController's content in the Container View. But using this navigation controller (Helper.shared.customNavController) I am not able to Push any other View Controller.

Comment: Yes you can embed nav controller inside your container view. Whats the piece of code that you have written to show second view controller inside container view?

Comment: I have updated the question with the code I tried. Maybe the problem with this line                            self.addChildViewController(navigationController)

Comment: You are adding secondViewController.view to containerView. Use containerView.addSubView(navigationController.view). Also play with setting the view's frame for navigation controller instead of second view controller's view frame.

Comment: Yes, I have wrongly added the SecondViewController's view as a subview instead of adding NavigationController's view. Saved my time. Thanks.

Comment: Is the code in your question a working final answer?