# How can I add the second View Controller into my ContainerView as well?

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I want to add my ViewController into the ContainerView of my ViewCtrl2. I do not really know how to add the subview to my ContainerView so that I can navigate forward and backwards. I hope someone can help me out!

I face some difficulties . I do not know how to go on from there. I instantiated my Views in my "actions"-Array but can´t go any further from there.

Comment: Kindly don't ask the same question multiple times.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add a ViewController into my Header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56391434/how-can-i-add-a-viewcontroller-into-my-header)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: StoryBoard]

**ContainerViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ContainerViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func btnOne(_ sender: Any) {
        containerView.subviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() } // removes the old if have
        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NavigationOneViewControllerID") as! NavigationOneViewController
        addChildView(viewController: nextViewController, in: containerView)
    }

    @IBAction func btnTwo(_ sender: Any) {
        containerView.subviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() } // removes the old if have
    }

    @IBAction func btnThree(_ sender: Any) {
        containerView.subviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() } // removes the old if have
    }

    private func addChildView(viewController: UIViewController, in DisView: UIView) {
        viewController.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
        viewController.view.frame = DisView.bounds
        addChild(viewController)
        DisView.addSubview(viewController.view)
        viewController.didMove(toParent: self)
    }

}
```

**NavigationOneViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class NavigationOneViewController: UINavigationController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

}
```

**ContainerSubOneViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ContainerSubOneViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func nxtClk(_ sender: Any) {
        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
        let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ContainerSubTwoViewControllerID") as! ContainerSubTwoViewController
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: true)
    }
}
```

**ContainerSubTwoViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
class ContainerSubTwoViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

}
```

Set the navigationOneViewController Top Bar to none in storyboard.

Comment: Do I have to do it for every controller? I have 6 navigation items with a a lot of structures..

Comment: yes. just change the `instantiateViewController` Identifier you have with 6 viewControllers.

Comment: Maybe I don´t get it right.. I already instantiated all ViewControllers with my "actions" Array.. Now I need to implement further navigation..Adding all the ViewControllers doesnßt solve the problem or am I wrong cause I already added them

Comment: ok. check this for that. i think this will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50363385/embed-container-view-with-navigation-controller-programmatically

Comment: Mhh I tried it but it always pushes a new controller over the complete view and not in my container view

Comment: but i tried and it works perfectly. updated the code.. check.