# How can I add a ViewController into my Header?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to add my ViewController into the header  of my `OverViewController`. I wrote an extension to add a Child View as a subview but I do not know how to add it into the header of my `ViewController`.

```
extension UIViewController {

    func add(_ child: UIViewController) {

        //add Child View controller
        addChildViewController(child)

        //add Child View as subview
        view.addSubview(child.view)

        //notify Child View Controller
        child.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    }
}
```

`ViewController` should be displayed in the header.

Comment: have you try with containerview

Comment: You can use [Container View](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide both the `childController` you want to add and the `view` of `parentController` in which you want to add the `childController`, i.e.

```
extension UIViewController {
    func addChild(_ controller: UIViewController, in containerView: UIView) {
        self.addChildViewController(controller)
        controller.view.frame = containerView.bounds
        containerView.addSubview(controller.view)
    }
}
```

In the above code:

1. `controller` - it is the `controller` that you want to add as child to other controller
2. `containerView` - the `view` of `parentController` in which you want to add the `childController`

**Usage:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let controller = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VC") {
            self.addChild(controller, in: self.containerView)
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code, I'm adding a `controller` with `identifier - VC` as child to `containerView`.

Comment: I did it like this before but my controller didn´t show up in the header.. I put a collectionView over my navigationItem and added my Controller as a child to my containerView

Comment: What is the issue you're facing with this? This code is working perfectly at my end. There might be some auto layout issue that the controller is not visible

Comment: Sorry for not responding.. I was too busy at work.. [Here](https://imgur.com/a/1b7YLRF) is the storyboard of my containerView.. As you can see the containerView is in my header.. I did the same coding as you but it is not showing up

Comment: I added the ProjectHeaderController into my containerView ( as shown in the picture)

Comment: There must be some issue with the code. Add more code so I can debug it.

Comment: There is no more code. [This](https://pastebin.com/zN7A8nfw) is the OverViewController and here´s the [Header](https://pastebin.com/R0Ub3FKy).. I miss something and I do not know what. There must be some issues with my storyboard where the container in my header does not show up

Comment: [Here](https://imgur.com/a/8on2JWT) is a picture from my storyboard and how it looks when I run the app

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the frame of your child view controller.

```
extension UIViewController {
    func add(_ child: UIViewController) {
        //add Child View controller
        addChildViewController(child)
        //add Child View as subview
        view.addSubview(child.view)
        //set the frame of the child view
        child.view.frame = view.bounds
        //notify Child View Controller
        child.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    }
}
```